# alternative way to compare if three ints are equal

Tags: java, operators, conditional-statements

```
int a = 10;
int b = 10;
int c = 10;
```

I am trying to find out if there is alternate way to compare if three ints or anything are equal.

The way i am currently doing is

```
if( (a == b) && (a == c) && (b == c)){

}
```

I was wondering if there is an alternate and more concise way to do this.

Comment: For many such ints you might use some set implementation and after adding them check number of elements

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Equality is transitive; you don't need the last comparison `b == c`.  If `a == b` and `a == c`, then `b == c`.

Try

```
if ((a == b) && (a == c)){
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is to know whether three are equal then you can use:

```
if ((a==b) && (b==c)) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

alternative variant:

```
int t1 = a-b;
int t2 = c-b;
if ( (t1|t2) == 0 ) // both are equal
```

Comment: This isn't really more compact than the other answers here, and is certainly less clear ;)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth it is not clear, but it is "alternative" :) also, can be a little bit faster (sometimes, at least for c/c++)

Comment: Are you saying that `0/0` equals `0` ?

Comment: @PM77-1: No, but `0|0` certainly does.

Comment: @PM77-1 I'm not using division, I'm using binary OR, 0|0 = 0 in deed

Comment: `if (0 == ((a - b) | (b - c)))` is equivalent, more compact, but even less clear. (Edit because didn't see Java tag)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth - I guess it's time to put my reading glasses on.

Comment: @Amadan for java you need to add == 0 or != 0 as it cannot cast int to bool automatically, for c/c++ it is of course shorter notation, but of course less clear :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int equal(int a, int b, int c) {
    int count = 0;

    if (a==b && b==c) { 
      count = 3; 
    } else if ((a==b && b!=c) || (a==c && a!=b)) { 
      count = 2; 
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question 
improves its long-term value. Consider reading [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and [edit] your answer to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add them into a list, then remove duplicates and compare the size of the actual list minus the unique elements

```
List elements = Arrays.asList(a,b,c);
List distinct = elements.stream().distinct().toList();

return elements.size() == distinct.size() ? 0 : elements.size() - distinct.size() + 1;
```

distinct list contains one entry of the duplicate so we have to increment with 1 because we already decreased it.

Or use a HashSet that holds only unique elements

```
List elements = Arrays.asList(a,b,c);
HashSet<ArrayList> set = new HashSet<>();
set.addAll(elements);

return elements.size() == set.size() ? 0 : elements.size() - set.size() + 1;
```